# I want to concatenate milliseconds to date format in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Dears,

I have a date value that has no milliseconds, and I want to concatenate System Timestamp milliseconds to that date.
I use GET_DATE_PART, but it didn't work.

What can I do regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly generate the values in two ports. One for original date value and the other for sysdate value. Take a variable port and substring sysdate value until the date before the milliseconds and print just the milliseconds. Finally in the other port concatenate your original date value with milliseconds. 
 If you can be able to post your codes, it would be more helpful to provide you relevant codes

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable port in expression transformation with the below logic and pass it to the next level, like:

```
ADD_TO_DATE(i_DATE,'MS',TO_INTEGER(TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP(),'MS')))
```

Replace `MS` with `NS` if you want Nanoseconds.

Hope this helps!